# How Blocking is avoided in 2-phase commit in Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have read that 2-phase commit suffers from Blocking problem.

But in the Google's Spanner Paper they had written that Google uses 2-phase commit in Spanner.

My question is that: How is this Blocking problem solved in Spanner?

Answer (score 2):

*"Some authors have claimed that general two-phase commit is too expensive to support, because of the performance or availability problems that it brings [9, 10, 19]. We believe it is better to have application programmers deal with performance problems due to overuse of transactions as bottlenecks arise, rather than always coding around the lack of transactions. Running two-phase commit over Paxos mitigates the availability problems."*

If one node down, Paxos could handle to read or write transactions from other alive nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Spanner is now available on Google Cloud Platform. Here are some additional docs about 2PC and locking.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions

==

Cloud Spanner allows multiple clients to simultaneously interact with the same database. In order to ensure the consistency of multiple concurrent transactions, Cloud Spanner uses a combination of shared locks and exclusive locks to control access to the data. When you perform a read as part of a transaction, Cloud Spanner acquires shared read locks, which allows other reads to still access the data until your transaction is ready to commit. When your transaction is committing and writes are being applied, the transaction attempts to upgrade to a exclusive lock. It blocks new shared read locks on the data, waits for existing shared read locks to clear, then places a exclusive lock for exclusive access to the data.

Notes about locks:

Locks are taken at the granularity of row-and-column. If transaction T1 has locked column "A" of row "foo", and transaction T2 wants to write column "B" of row "foo" then there is no conflict.
Writes to a data item that don't also read the data being written (aka "blind writes") don't conflict with other blind writers of the same item (the commit timestamp of each write determines the order in which it is applied to the database). A consequence of this is that Cloud Spanner only needs to upgrade to an exclusive lock if you have read the data you are writing. Otherwise Cloud Spanner uses a shared lock called a writer shared lock.

==